# Firebase database notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-notifications

In my android app I start a service when the user exits the app:

```
ArrayList<String> eventKeys = new ArrayList<>();
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("eventKeys", eventKeys);
startService(intent);
```

Then in my service:

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

     (fields)...

     @Nullable
     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
         if (intent == null) {
             System.out.println("ERROR");
             return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
         }
         eventKeys = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get("eventKeys");

         //here I attach listeners to firebase database
         firebase();

         new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (notifyMessage) {
                        sendNotification("You have a new message.");
                        stopSelf();
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Sleeping...");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;
     }
```

And the following produces prints out Sleeping... just one time and after that ERROR. If I remove the null check I get a null pointer. If I remove the firebase method It works.

```
private void firebase(List<String> eventKeys) {
    System.out.println("Set database listener");
    mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events");

    for (String eventKey : eventKeys){

        mDataBase.child(eventKey).child("chat").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //new message received
                notifyMessage = true;
                sendNotification("You have a new message.");
                stopSelf();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
}
```

This does not work and I don't have any idea what to do.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any specific error. The notification, however, is not sent when I change the child. I didn't mention that this code is executed when I close the app.

Comment: You're ignoring potential error when attaching your listener. Implement `onCancelled` as I just wrote up here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=201609121647524851802

Answer (score 1):

Did you declared your service in manifest?

```
 <manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".MyService " />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

You don't need to create new Thread in service class, because Service by itself is an background operation. Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: When I remove the thread, the code is working for a while and after that I get: 'Thread[3,tid=29740,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread: reacting to signal 3'

Comment: Retrieving data from Firebase is an async method, so after `firebase()` method call, code execution is still going. You should do Thread job inside `onChildChanged()` method to ensure that your notification is shown, because using that aproach it can change your `notifyMessage ` value. And i can see that you are starting new `childEventListener` for each key and use same boolean value.

Comment: Ok. I did it like this. The ChildEventListener is entering onChildAdded but doesn't want to enter onChildChanged.

Comment: I think `onChildChanged()` method is called when a child is modified from another source (console or other network calls). Try changing some property from Firebase console and see if that method is called.

Comment: Yes, that's right and I do that but the method is not invoked.

Comment: It should be called, but i don't know why not is called. Rest of that 3 methods are called when you edit something in console?

Comment: Only onChildAdded is called returning the database objects just one time. When I add a new one it is not called. The other methods are not called as well.

Comment: I think is because you create multiple listeners for each key. I don't know if that is right, if it will be just one instance with the last key or other problem. You try to add new listener for each new message?

Comment: No just for each event that the user is in. The event has chat node and that is where I attach the listener.

Comment: So this event it should be just one, no? Current conversation. Try add this childEventListener on a activity/fragment to check if is changing when the app is running, if not, it can be a Firebase bug.

Comment: Well, it works when the app is running. I will try to check everything again to see if I miss something. Thank you for the ideas.

Comment: For nothing. If you have other questions, post them here. You can accept this answer if you want :D